# How to display UITextFields inside of UITableViewCells in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Hi i have one button in `UIView`. My requirement is if i click that button `UITextField`s displayed in `UITableViewCells`. I am having idea how to display the `UITextField`s in `UIView` if user clicks the button. But i dont have any idea how to display `UITextField`s inside of `UITableViewCell`s if user hits the button.Please help me anybody.

```
 UIButton *myGreenIconButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [myGreenIconButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(GreenIconButtonClicked)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [myGreenIconButton1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"index.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    myGreenIconButton1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    myGreenIconButton1.frame = CGRectMake(285, 144, 25, 25);

    [self.view addSubview:myGreenIconButton1];


    -(void)GreenIconButtonClicked

    {

    UITextField *text1=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 20)];

    text1.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    text1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    text1.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

    text1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    text1.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

    text1.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    text1.delegate=self;

    [self.view addSubview:text1];


    UITextField *text2=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 80, 100, 20)];

    text2.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    text2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    text2.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

    text2.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    text2.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

    text2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    text2.delegate=self;

    [self.view addSubview:text2];

    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

    {

    return 1;

    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

    {

    return 1;

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) 

    {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:@""];

    return cell;

    }
```

Comment: Be specific to what you want to achieve , Make all the basic concepts clear at first. Read the UITableView Controller, UITableViewCell classes and their references from apple docs first. Best luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this:

```
[yourSubview setTag:101];
[cell.contentView addSubview:yourSub];
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

And you can restore your textField like this:

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip]
UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
```

Pay attention to 101 - it is number you can use for tag. And different views (for ex: cell.contentView) may contain equal tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass `UITableViewCell` and add in an outlet for your textfield.  Lot of examples out there if you look for them.  Here is one:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/

Something like this (`MyCustomTableViewCell.h`):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
@end
```

And then in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.myTextField.text = @"Whatever";
```

Don't forget to `#import "MyCustomTableViewCell.h"` and also wire up that textfield in IB